# What is the production order of digimon?

Tags: digimon, digimon-tri, digimon-tamers

What is the production order of the digimon anime? I've seen season 1 with Tai and Augumon and season 2 with Davis and Veemon. But what's the proper order to continue?

Comment: just to confirm. you are talking about the release dates of the various series right? do you also include the Movies?

Comment: @memor-x yes, and yes. I want to consume it entirely but in proper order.

Answer (score 3):

The Production Release Order is as follows (these are the Japanese Air Dates):

- [Digimon Adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Adventure) - March 7, 1999 to March 26, 2000 **[Series]**

  - [Digimon Adventure Movie (Part one of Digimon: The Movie)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Adventure#Digimon_Adventure) - March 6, 1999<sup>1</sup> **[Movie]**
  - [Digimon Adventure: Our War Game (Part two of Digimon: The Movie)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Adventure#Our_War_Game.21) - March 4, 2000<sup>1</sup> **[Movie]**
- [Digimon Adventure 02](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Adventure_02) - April 2, 2000, and March 25, 2001 **[Series]**

  - [Digimon Adventure 02: Digimon Hurricane Jōriku / Chōzetsu Shinka!! Ōgon no Digimental (Part three of Digimon: The Movie)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Adventure_02#Films) - July 8, 2000 **[Movie]**
  - [Digimon Adventure 3D: Digimon Grandprix!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Digimon_films#Digimon_Grandprix.21) - July 20, 2000<sup>2</sup> **[OVA]**
  - [Digimon Adventure 02: Revenge of Diaboromon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Adventure_02#Revenge_of_Diaboromon) - March 3, 2001 **[Movie]**
- [Digimon Tamers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Tamers) - April 1, 2001 to March 31, 2002 **[Series]**

  - [Digimon Tamers: Battle of Adventurers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Digimon_films#Battle_of_Adventurers) - July 14, 2001 **[Movie]**
  - [Digimon Tamers: Runaway Locomon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Digimon_films#Runaway_Locomon) - March 2, 2002 **[Movie]**
- [Digimon Frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Frontier) - April 7, 2002 to March 30, 2003 **[Series]**

  - [Digimon Frontier: Island of Lost Digimon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Digimon_films#Digimon_Frontier:_Island_of_Lost_Digimon) - July 20, 2002 **[Movie]**
- [Digital Monster X-Evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Digimon_films#Digital_Monster_X-Evolution) - January 3, 2005 **[Movie]**
- [Digimon Savers (Digimon Data Squad)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Data_Squad) - April 2, 2006 to March 25, 2007 **[Series]**

  - [Digimon Savers 3D: The Digital World in Imminent Danger!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Digimon_films#The_Digital_World_in_Imminent_Danger.21) - July 8, 2006 <sup>2</sup> **[OVA]**
  - [Digimon Savers: Ultimate Power! Activate Burst Mode!!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Digimon_films#Ultimate_Power.21_Activate_Burst_Mode.21.21) -  December 9, 2006 **[Movie]**
- [Digimon Xros Wars (Digimon Fusion)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Fusion) - July 6, 2010 to March 21, 2012 **[Series]**
- [Digimon Adventure tri.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Adventure_tri.) **[Movie Series]**

  - Episode 1 - November 21, 2015
  - Episode 2 - March 12, 2016
  - Episode 3 - September 24, 2016
  - Episode 4 - February 25, 2017
  - Episode 5 - TBA
  - Episode 6 - TBA
- [Digimon Universe: Appli Monsters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Universe:_Appli_Monsters) - October 1, 2016 - Ongoing **[Series]**

Main Source - [Digimon on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon)

i would think that Digimon Adventure Tri is expected to be watched together however only half of the series was released before Digimon Universe. plot wise Digimon Universe is set in 2045 while Digimon Adventure Tri is set 3 years after Digimon Adventure 02 which itself is set 3 years after Digimon Adventure. Digimon Adventure was set in 1999 so this means Digimon Adventure Tri is set somewhere in 2005.

this year might be off depending on how much time passed in the previous 2 seasons but even then Digimon Adventure Tri's plot is set a few decades before Digimon Universe

---

<sup>1: these 3 movies were later released in the US as Digimon: The Movie on October 6, 2000</sup>

<sup>2: this was the first date it aired however as wikipedia says it was later included on a bonus disc in the Digimon THE MOVIES Blu-ray 1999-2006 compilation, released on January 9, 2015</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon), here is the suggested watching order (films in italics, ignoring shorter films and side material like games and manga):

- Digimon Adventure (aka Digimon Season 1)

  - The first series, introducing the original DigiDestined and their partners
- Digimon Adventure 02 (aka Digimon Season 2)

  - A direct sequel to Digimon Adventure
- *Digimon: The Movie* (actually formed from three shorter Digimon Adventure movies)
- *Digimon Adventure 02: Diaboromon Strikes Back* (aka *Diaboromon Returns*)

  - Apparently never had a DVD release in the West, so not sure how you watch that officially these days
- Digimon Tamers

  - Set in a world where the original series are just animated TV shows
- *Digimon Tamers: Battle of Adventurers*
- *Digimon Tamers: Runaway Digimon Express* (aka *Runaway Locomon*)
- Digimon Frontier

  - In which the DigiDestined merge with Digimon spirits rather than having them as separate entities
- *Digimon Frontier: Revival of the Ancient Digimon* (aka *Island of Lost Digimon*)
- *Digital Monster X-Evolution*

  - Never released internationally, and not connected with any other series
- Digimon Savers (aka Digimon Data Squad)
- *Digimon Savers: Ultimate Power! Activate Burst Mode!!*

  - Never released internationally
- Digimon Xros Wars (aka Digimon Fusion)
- Digimon Adventure tri.

  - Featuring the return of the original DigiDestined, the season is being released in four parts, with the final part due for release in Japanese in February
- Digimon Universe: Appli Monsters

  - Currently with no official English release

In terms of continuity, having watched the first two seasons of Adventure you can pretty much watch anything - Digimon: The Movie and Digimon Adventure tri. are the only things that follow on directly from the original show, each other show and related movies form separate continuities.

I would also personally suggest that at some point you watch the film *Summer Wars*, which is essentially Digimon: The Movie taken away from the Digimon universe and made many times better.